# Problem with database query created by EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to download the filtered data from the database.

Here it filters the data

```
return predicate
                .And(true, () => company => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria.Keyword) ? searchCriteria.Keyword.Contains(company.Name) : true)
                .Or(true, () => company => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria.Keyword) ? company.Employees.Any(x => x.FirstName == searchCriteria.Keyword) : true)
                .Or(true, () => company => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria.Keyword) ? company.Employees.Any(x => x.LastName == searchCriteria.Keyword) : true)
                .And(true, () => company => searchCriteria.EmployeeDateOfBirthFrom != null ? company.Employees.Any(x => x.DateOfBirth >= searchCriteria.EmployeeDateOfBirthFrom) : true)
                .And(true, () => company => searchCriteria.EmployeeDateOfBirthTo != null ? company.Employees.Any(x => x.DateOfBirth <= searchCriteria.EmployeeDateOfBirthTo) : true)
                .And(true, () => company => searchCriteria.EmployeeJobTitles != null ? company.Employees.Any(x=> searchCriteria.EmployeeJobTitles.Any(s=> s == x.JobTitle.ToString())) : true);
```

and here I am downloading data from the database:

```
 return await dbContext.Companies.Include(x => x.Employees).Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
```

Why I have this problem and Can I fix it ?

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Employee>
    .Where(e => EF.Property<Nullable<long>>((EntityShaperExpression: 
        EntityType: Company
        ValueBufferExpression: 
            (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
        IsNullable: False
    ), "Id") != null && EF.Property<Nullable<long>>((EntityShaperExpression: 
        EntityType: Company
        ValueBufferExpression: 
            (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
        IsNullable: False
    ), "Id") == EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(e, "CompanyId"))
    .Any(e => __searchCriteria_EmployeeJobTitles_0
        .Contains(e.ToString()))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.<VisitMethodCall>g__CheckTranslated|8_0(ShapedQueryExpression translated, <>c__DisplayClass8_0& )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF Core cannot translate the following expression:

```
company.Employees.Any(x => searchCriteria.EmployeeJobTitles
    .Any(s => s == x.JobTitle.ToString()))
```

There are two issues with it.

First, `searchCriteria.EmployeeJobTitles` seems to be in-memory collection, and the only currently translatable operator on in-memory collections is `Contains`.

So it should be changed to

```
company.Employees.Any(x => searchCriteria.EmployeeJobTitles
    .Contains(x.JobTitle.ToString()))
```

But according to the exception message you already did that. Which leads us to the second issue: `x.JobTitle` property type seems to be enum, and `ToString()` for enums cannot be translated.

So you have to perform the enum filter other way around - convert `searchCriteria.EmployeeJobTitles` from `IEnumerable<string>` to `IEnumerable<JobTitle>` and use `Contains(x.JobTitle)`, this avoiding `x.JobTitle.ToString()`:

```
company.Employees.Any(x => searchCriteria.EmployeeJobTitles
    .Select(t => Enum.Parse<JobTitle>(t))
    .Contains(x.JobTitle))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `x.JobTitle.ToString()` to `x.JobTitle` when building your predicate. `ToString()` isn’t supported on the database side.

Comment: I changed it to:

```.And(true, () => company => searchCriteria.EmployeeJobTitles != null ? company.Employees.Any(x=> searchCriteria.EmployeeJobTitles.Any(s=> (JobTitle)Enum.Parse(typeOf(JobTitle), s) == x.JobTitle)) : true);```
it still does not work